# Getting Javascript Memory Profiling During Test Suite

Tags: javascript, memory, memory-leaks, build, phantomjs

We inherited a fairly large Javascript application and test suite and have recently started to have issues with memory usage during testing.

Whilst we attempt to fix the issues our test suite has, we'd like to stem the flow of new leaks into the application. Are there any tools that we can integrate with our CI build to get memory profiling? Even some basic memory allocation statistics would help us see whether a suite is eating through memory.

We're running Jasmine with PhantomJS. The closest I've been able to find is Chrome's window.performance.memory, but it's only for the whole of Chrome and seems like it might be quite volatile.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any automated memory statistics 3rd party applications for javascript that would work in CI. Take a look at Google's memory profiling post: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling

Comment: Also take a look at these posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687499/unit-tests-karma-runner-jasmine-profiling and http://www.slideshare.net/mayflowergmbh/plugging-holes-javascript-memory-leak-debugging.